# Get all Firestore documents after specific date

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, real-time-updates

What I try to accomplish is the following: I have a collection where documents get added with a timestamp in them. I then want to listen to that collection via snapshotlistener, but just for new documents. So I update my timestamp to the newest document-timestamp received, and try to query only the documents newer than my timestamp. In onCreate I assign `lastUpdateTime` a date in the past, so that I get the first document added.

```
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US)
    try {
        lastUpdateTime = sdf.parse("01/01/2000")

    } catch (e: ParseException) {
       //
    }
```

then I add the `snapshotlistener` and try to update `lastUpdateTime` in order to just look for documents newer than thist Date/Time

```
val path = //...path to my collection
private var lastUpdateTime = Any() //my up-to-date timestamp. I first assign it some date in the past, to make sure it gets the first document added.
// some code

talksListener = path.whereGreaterThan("timestamp", lastUpdateTime)
                .addSnapshotListener(EventListener<QuerySnapshot> { snapshot, e ->

                    if (snapshot != null && !snapshot.isEmpty && !snapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites()) {                            

                        for (dSnapshot in snapshot) {
                            val thisTimestamp = dSnapshot.get("timestamp")    

                            if (thisTimestamp != null) {
                                lastUpdateTime = thisTimestamp
                            }  
                        }
                    }
                })
```

But every time I add an document, I get the whole collection again.
I also tried all combinations with `orderBy` and `startAt/endAt/startBefore/EndBefore` but the result is the same. Either I get nothing, or the whole collection every time a new document is added.
for example:

```
talksListener = path.orderBy("timestamp").startAfter(lastUpdateTime)
```

Where is the problem here?
Also, on a different note, is there a possibility to include `!snapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites()` into the query in Kotlin. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) says to use `MetadataChanges.INCLUDE` but I do not get how to implement it in Kotlin. Every Hint is much appreciated.

**edit 1:**
My firestore DB is structured like this:

```
users/{user}/messages/{message} -> here is the timestamp located
```

and my path leads to `./messages`

**edit 2:** 
the solution is to detach and reattach the listener after the new lastUpdateTime is assigned. That does not sound good to me, so if anyone has a better solution, I am happy to hear it. For the time being I will stick to it though.

Comment: Please edit your question to be very specific about the value of `lastUpdateTime` at the time you pass it in.  FYI, the `@ServerTimestamp` annotation is not going to help you at all with values passed to queries.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ok, I tried to make I clearer. Thanks for the info.

Comment: And if you log that date just before the query, it contains exactly the date you'd like to query against?  Are you certain that the `timestamp` field in your documents is really a timestamp data type (and not something else, like a number)?

Comment: Also it's worth noting that, without seeing all the data in the data set you're querying, there's no way to know for sure if you're actually getting the right set of documents.

Comment: yes if I log the timestamp inside the listener, the latest date will be assigned to lastUpdateTime. Yes timestamp in firestore is a timestamp data type.